# 'mc.cores' > 1 is not supported on Windows

Tags: r, windows, parallel-processing, multicore

I am new to programming and I am trying to use parallel processing for R in windows, using an existing code.

Following is the snippet of my code:

---

```
if (length(grep("linux", R.version$os)) == 1){
    num_cores = detectCores()
    impact_list <- mclapply(len_a, impact_func, mc.cores = (num_cores - 1))
  } 
  # else if(length(grep("mingw32", R.version$os)) == 1){
  #   num_cores = detectCores()
  #   impact_list <- mclapply(len_a, impact_func, mc.cores = (num_cores - 1))
  # 
  # }
  else{
    impact_list <- lapply(len_a, impact_func)
  }
  return(sum(unlist(impact_list, use.names = F)))
```

This works fine, I am using R on windows so the code enters in 'else' statement and it runs the code using lapply() and not by parallel processing.

---

I have added the 'else if' statement to make it work for windows. So when I un-comment 'else if' block of code and run it, I am getting an error "'mc.cores' > 1 is not supported on Windows". 
Please suggest how can I use parallel processing in windows, so that less time is taken to run the code.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf and https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/.

Comment: Or the future packages, intro [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-1-overview.html)

Comment: `furrr` is a good addition to `future` package. Be aware that parallelism is not the same on Windows than on Linux. You won't be able to use forking, only multi session. There are also some caveats when launched from RStudio.

Answer (score 3):

(disclaimer: I'm author of the future framework here)

The [**future.apply**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future.apply) package provides parallel versions of R's built-in "apply" functions.  It's cross platform, i.e. it works on Linux, macOS, and Windows. The package allows you to often just replace an existing `lapply()` with a `future_lapply()` call, e.g.

```r
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)

your_fcn <- function(len_a) {
  impact_list <- future_lapply(len_a, impact_func)
  sum(unlist(impact_list, use.names = FALSE))
}
```

**Regarding mclapply()** per se: If you use `parallel::mclapply()` in your code, make sure that there is always an option *not* to use it.  The reason is that it is not guaranteed to work in all environment, that is, it might be unstable and crash R.  In R-devel thread 'mclapply returns NULLs on MacOS when running GAM' (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2020-April/079384.html), the author of `mclapply()` wrote on 2020-04-28:

> *Do NOT use mcparallel() in packages except as a non-default option that user can set for the reasons Henrik explained. Multicore is intended for HPC applications that need to use many cores for computing-heavy jobs, but it does not play well with RStudio and more importantly you don't know the resource available so only the user can tell you when it's safe to use. Multi-core machines are often shared so using all detected cores is a very bad idea. The user should be able to explicitly enable it, but it should not be enabled by default.*